# Azure blob storage, How do I change the name of the file being downloaded?

Tags: azure, blob

I have an app that is used to download files from Azure blob via node js and I want to change the name of the file while downloading. For instance, if the filename is `XYZ_ABC.txt` I want the filename after downloading to be `ABC.txt`.

```
const { DefaultAzureCredential } = require("@azure/identity");
const { BlobServiceClient } = require("@azure/storage-blob");

const account = "<account>";
const defaultAzureCredential = new DefaultAzureCredential();

const blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(
  `https://${account}.blob.core.windows.net`,
  defaultAzureCredential
);

const containerName = "<container name>";
const blobName = "<blob name>";

async function main() {
  const containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(containerName);
  const blobClient = containerClient.getBlobClient(blobName);

  
  return await blobClient.download().then(response=>{   

            return {message:"File Downloaded)", data:response, responseCode:200};

        }).catch(err=>{
            console.log(`download  failed`, err);
            return {message:"download failed", data:err, responseCode:400};
        });  
}catch(ex){

    return {message:"Failed to Download", data:ex, responseCode:400};
}     
main();
```

Above is the code. How do I change the name of the file being downloaded?

Comment: Please edit your question and include the code you have written.

Comment: I included the code...Can you check it

Comment: Where in your code are you returning the file/data?

Comment: @GauravMantri my bad...edited it now

Comment: Thanks. Is your code part of a web application or are you simply running in console? As I can see, you are simply returning an object that contains blob data among other things.

Comment: It's a part of web application...major focus is on changing the filename...functionality wise it's all good

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the blob data downloaded, you'll need to invoke the browser download process from the local data. One option to do this is to use a library like [Filesaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js), which allows setting the download file name as a parameter:

```
var FileSaver = require('file-saver');
var blob = new Blob(["Hello, world!"], {type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"});
FileSaver.saveAs(blob, "hello world.txt");
```

Comment: Thank you Noah..will try